# Dependency Injection in C++ use pointer or object?

Tags: c++, dependency-injection

While I am learning C++ based on how develop in modern PHP frameworks I decided to use the Dependency Injection pattern with services as Singletons.

For making myself clear let suppose we have the collowing classes:

```
class B {
  public:
    B(){};
}

class A{
  public:
    // Dependency Injecting class B into class A
    A(B b):b(b){}
  private:
   const B b;
}
```

So in this example I wondered if I will gain better performance if I used pointer instead of an Object. In other words would it be better if class `A` had been:

```
class A{
  public:
    // Dependency Injecting class B into class A
    A(B* b):b(b){}
  private:
   const B *b;
}
```

Also, what is the downside in the pointer-based approach?

Comment: I would love the long answer as well.

Comment: "`const B* b;`" Not related, but I think you should really use spaces according to grammar: `const B *b;` because grouping is `const B;` and `*b`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So in this example I wondered if I will gain better performance if I used pointer instead of an Object.

No.

I will be very surprised if that is the case.

> Also, what is the downside in the pointer-based approach?

You'll have to define ownership policy of the object that the pointer points to. If the client is expected to retain ownership of the object,

1. The client of `A` has to make sure that the pointer is valid as long as the `A` object is alive.
2. Behavior of `A` will be unpredictable since it depends on the client to make sure that the pointer stays valid.

If `A` is expected to take over ownership of the object,

1. You'll have to make sure the object that the pointer points to is deleted before the `A` object is destructed.
2. You'll have to make sure to follow [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) so that copy construction and copy assignment are dealt with correctly.

Comment: Would the use of smart pointers change anything here?  I can see how the use of normal pointers would be a nightmare solution.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch, it would help with the issues related to The Rule of Three but you still have to be clear on the ownership policy. That would dictate whether you use `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Thank you.  In the realm of C# and Java, there is a container that initializes all of the objects in use in the system.  It's responsibility is to ensure the order of initialization is done such that the leaves of the DAG are built first.  The container is also responsible for tearing down all of the objects.  Granted that doesn't work the same verbatim in C++.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch, I have some experience in C# and no experience in Java. I can't compare between what C# and Java do vs. what C++ does.

Answer (score 4):

You also need to ask the reverse: what is the downside to using an object directly?

The answer is that the object version captures a `B b` and will not permit an arbitrary subclass of `B` to be injected — unless it offers a lossy conversion to `B`.

If `B` alone has sufficient customization for your scenario, maybe that's fine.  But the pointer version will directly accept subclasses of `B` as well as plain `B`s.

Since the purpose is injection, I would presume that accepting subclasses of B might sometimes be of interest here.  YMMV.

Comment: So for DI a pointer version  is preferred right? Usually, it is common to have a Superclass or in other Languages an Interface. In C++ case because no intefaces are offered hence a SuperClass may be required therefore a pointer is a way to go.  Right?

Comment: Yes, that's often the case.  (You might use smart pointers to establish the ownership  as @RSahu is getting at.)